# Echo issue, loops 4 times

Tags: php

I have this code

```
'$a = "pippo";
$b = "lucia";

for ($i=0;$i<strlen($a);$i++)
{
  $c = "$a";
  echo "$c";
}'
```

When I run it I see four times pippo instead of one time. Why does it happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$c = $a[$i];` - use `$i` as the character index to the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It echos 'pippo' five times (pippopippopippopippopippo), because your loop says that it should. You start with $i = 0, the loop will continue while that is true. Every time your loop runs $i is incremented by 1. It will stop when the condition $i

**Example:**

$i = 0

$i = 1

$i = 2

$i = 3

$i = 4

$i = 5 (Will not execute loop, because condition $i<5 is not true anymore)